# App deployed to Gcloud can't write JS files when compiling TS?

Tags: typescript, gcloud

I added some TS code to an existing nodejs application.

The first time I pulled the project from GitHub to gcloud it all worked fine.

This time, I made some changes, added some more TS files, and now the application won't run after deployment.

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

The logs show a bunch of failures to write the JS versions of my TS files.

```
{
 insertId: "5eb4e6c8000b9ff215033be3"  
 labels: {…}  
 logName: "projects/ncatsidg-dev/logs/stdout"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-05-08T04:57:44.821184556Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 textPayload: "error TS5033: Could not write file '/srv/src/models/DataModelList.js': EROFS: read-only file system, open '/srv/src/models/DataModelList.js'."  
 timestamp: "2020-05-08T04:57:44.761842Z"  
}
```

I get that the gcloud deployment is read-only, but it should be able to compile TS and deploy. I have a compilation step in my package.json, which is supposed to compile TS to JS for gcloud ([so sayeth this internet page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/running-custom-build-step)), but alas, something no workie!

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node src/index.js & jest",
    "start": "tsc && nodemon src/index.js",
    "start:ci": "tsc && node src/index.js",
    "gcp-build": "tsc -p ."
  },
```

Comment: This comment doesn't answer your question, but a possible solution might be to use [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) package to execute your nodejs ts files without the compilation step.

Comment: From the error message you might be trying to write to the `DataModelList.js` file which is not allowed because the [App Engine filesystem](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#filesystem) is read-only except for the `/tmp` directory.

Comment: I see that the directory can't be written to, but shouldn't gcloud app deploy be handling that, i.e. compiling, then moving the files in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies.

Turns out gcloud app deploy is smart enough to compile TS and deploy the JS.

But I *outsmarted* it when I changed my start command to

```
"start": "tsc && nodemon src/index.js"
```

So it was trying to recompile the JS files again when the app was run, but it was already done, so that wasn't necessary.

When I removed the tsc in that start command, it worked as intended.

Comment: Good work finding the solution! Can you [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!